# how to copy particular text inside pre tag using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Need to copy the text given inside the `<pre>` tag using selenium python

```
<div id="response_headers" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <pre>
    "test test1 test2"
    </pre>
</div>
```

Please guide me to copy those test2 inside `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe like

```
preTextEl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='response_headers']/pre")
print preTextEl.text
```

Or using CssSelector:

```
preTextEl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id='response_headers'] pre")
print preTextEl.text
```